# How to repopulate my login form when the validation fail

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator, connect-flash

I in login form when the validation is failed i am able to show the validation error messages but i am not getting how to repopulate the login form.

what i want that the user should not enter his email address again in case of validation errors.

what i have done so far that i am trying to get email value as i am sending error back from passport.js using connect-flash.

my passport local strategy is.

```
passport.use(
  "local.signin",
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: "email",
      passwordField: "password",
      passReqToCallback: true
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) {
      console.log("I am in passport");
      req.checkBody("email", "invalid email")
      .notEmpty()
      .isEmail();
      req.checkBody("password",'invalid password')
      .notEmpty();
      req.flash('email',email);
      req.flash('password',password);
      var errors = req.validationErrors();

        if(errors){
          var messages = [];
          errors.forEach((error) => {
              messages.push(error.msg);
          });
        console.log("errors: ", errors);
          return done(null, false, req.flash("error", messages));
        }
        User.findOne({email:email}, (err, user) => {
          if(err){
            return done(err);
          }
          if(!user){
            return done(null, false, {message: "No user found!"});
          }
          if(!user.validPassword(password)){
            return done(null, false, {message: "Wrong Password"});
          }
          return done(null, user);
        });
    }
  )
);
```

and the index function which the route redirect to after validation is failed

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
        var messages = req.flash("error");
        console.log("email: ",req.flash('email'));
    res.render("admin/index", {
      layout: "loginSignup",
      messages: messages,
      hasErrors: messages.length > 0,
      email: req.flash('email'),
      password: req.flash('password')
    });
};
```

Here when i console.log(); it shows empty array, email and password is not saved in flash and so i am not able to populate input field in view

i am not getting what is wrong with my code, when i can get error message why not email and password values.

or is there better way of repopulating the form in nodejs

Comment: can you `console.log(req.flash('email'))` inside your exported index method?

Comment: yes but is giving empty array

Comment: after `console.log("I am in passport");` try `console.log(email)`;

Comment: after console.log(email) i can see the email in console

Comment: very weird. Do you assign any value of `req.flash` object in `res.locals` object?

Answer (score 0):

Why not try something like this?

```
res.render("admin/index", {
  layout: "loginSignup",
  messages: messages,
  hasErrors: messages.length > 0,
  email: req.body('email') || '',
  password: req.body('password') || ''
});
```

Note, this is assuming the route is mounted on an app.post() call and you are using the bodyparser middleware, if you are using app.get(), then change req.body for req.params in my example.

Comment: hey thank you. but it is a app.get(); and i am using passport when there is a validation error i redirect to this url. i tried your solution but giving me undefined value.

Answer (score 0):

assign req.body to flash and then send back on validation error redirect like so

```
passport.use(
  "local.signin",
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: "email",
      passwordField: "password",
      passReqToCallback: true
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) {
      req.checkBody("email", "invalid email")
      .notEmpty()
      .isEmail();
      req.checkBody("password",'invalid password')
      .notEmpty();
      var form =  req.flash("form",req.body);
      var errors = req.validationErrors();

        if(errors){
          var messages = [];
          errors.forEach((error) => {
              messages.push(error.msg);
          });
        console.log("errors: ", errors);
          return done(null, false, {
              error: req.flash("error", messages),
              form: form
               });
        }
        User.findOne({email:email}, (err, user) => {
          if(err){
            return done(err);
          }
          if(!user){
            return done(null, false, {message: "No user found!", form: form});
          }
          if(!user.validPassword(password)){
            return done(null, false, {message: "Wrong Password", form: form});
          }
          return done(null, user);
        });
    }
  )
);
```

and the on the redirect route get the req.body from form variable and send to your view in the following code as

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
        var messages = req.flash("error");
    res.render("admin/index", {
      layout: "loginSignup",
      messages: messages,
      hasErrors: messages.length > 0,
      form : req.flash("form")
    });
};
```